# How to get a Dir for .ext of Folder

Tags: iphone, directory, file-extension, dir

I am creating a iPhone Application that accesses a Folder on the iPhone that has a random extension. For example: folder.g1Polt . Now I have access to this folder since I know my .ext by looking into my files, but it will only work for MY device. How can I retrieve isDir for the actual .ext  Below you can see the working code that retrieves the files from this folder but I need to get rid of that .g1Polt and have just

NSString *path = @"/private/var/stash/Themes/";

```
NSString *path = @"/private/var/stash/Themes.g1Polt/";
contentOfFolder = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:path];
NSLog(@"contentOfFolder: %@", contentOfFolder);
directoriesOfFolder = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
for (NSString *aPath in contentOfFolder) {
    NSString * fullPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:aPath];

    BOOL isDir;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&isDir] &&  
isDir) {
        [directoriesOfFolder addObject: fullPath];
    }
}
NSLog(@"dirctories %@", directoriesOfFolder);    

[directoriesOfFolder addObjectsFromArray:contentOfFolder];
```

Answer (score 0):

It really is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

What I can tell you is that you will no be able to access files outside of your `sandbox` on the iPhone so you will not be able to get to those files anyway. See the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3) for more on the sandbox

Basically you should be working within your own Documents directory.

Comment: Well I ended up going a different route to avoid this. In my defense you can certainly access files on your device. With just a few simple lines of code and NSFileManager . I am not saying this is apple API but it is possible